# Is it disrespectful for a non Muslim to wear the traditional clothing

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim, clothing

I am not a Muslim, but have nothing but the highest respect for your faith.  I am not Muslim but admire the clothing, is it disrespectful to Allah to wear the clothing?

Comment: Clothing in particular have nothing to do with religion except for covering certain parts of our body which differs for men and women therefore opposite sex will not be so seduced which drives them to committing other sins (lets say for example a women chest is attractive in a males view, seeing topless women will always alter mans thinking to a sexual way, at some point or another in some ones consensus)

Comment: Short answer not disrespectful at all and your more than welcome to, traditional cloth often is related to culture and in case of religions it explains why priests and nuns dress nearly same as Muslims

Comment: why should it be-- unless you'll be wearing it to mock them or to work a hidden agenda, which you don't sound like you will. just my personal thoughts-- not a scholar or anything.

Answer (score 2):

Islam specifies an abstract minimum level of clothing for men and women - the actual concrete dress forms are tied to a local culture, not the religion itself. There is nothing inherently "Islamic" about Muslim clothing other than it conforms to that guidance. So no, there is nothing disrespectful at all about wearing clothing that is found in Muslim lands.

Comment: (adding to your answer) as long as the intent is not to mislead anyone. For instance, a non-Muslim may not wear the clothes typically worn by Muslim religious scholars, since it could mislead them into assuming that person to be what he isn't, and accepting anything that he may say. Having said that, let me also add that there is no dress formally designated to be worn by scholars, and it may vary from region to region.